# Missing CD Quality, Lossy profile in Preferred Formats in RhythmBox

Tags: rhythmbox, ogg-vorbis

Good evening all,

I am having a problem with RhythmBox on Ubuntu 10.10.  I freshly installed Ubuntu almost a week ago and everything was great right off the bat.  However, tonight I am having a small issue.  In RhythmBox, I went into the Preferences section and went to check the quality level of the the CD Quality, Lossy profile (the ones that uses ogg) and it is missing from the Preferred Formats list.  If I click the Edit button, I see it in the list of available profiles along with many others and it is set to active.  Why would it not be in the Preferred Formats list, and more importantly, how could I get it back in the Preferred Formats list so I can rip a CD with it?  Just as a side note, RhythmBox is playing ogg files without problem.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.  Evidently, some of the values in the GStreamer pipeline string were not just right.  I found the default setting and set it to that and it is now showing in the list.